# Mongoose : Queries through an array, return a promise of an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to iterate through `opts` and make the same query on each element, I want in return a promise of an array containing the results of the queries. How can I do that ?

I tried for the moment with only the first item

```
//opts is an array of objects
function getRecapOfCampaign (campaignId, opts) {    
  var p_votes = Models.BSVote
    .find({
      created: {
        $gte: opts[0].fromDate,
        $lt: opts[0].toDate
      }
    })
    .where('campaign').equals(campaignId)
    .count()
    .exec();

  return p_votes;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of promise libs out there you could use for this or you could use the native JS [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) implementation on the newer releases of Node. In particular the [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method.

```
Promise.all([ARRAY_OR_PROMISES]).then(values => {
  console.log(values); // [ARRAY_OF_RESULTS_FROM_PROMISES]
});
```

Using `Promise.all` along with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should give you exactly what you want:

```
//opts is an array of objects
function getRecapOfCampaign(campaignId, opts) {
  return Promise.all(opts.map(function(opt) {
    return Models.BSVote.find({
        created: {
          $gte: opt.fromDate,
          $lt: opt.toDate
        }
      })
      .where('campaign').equals(campaignId)
      .count()
      .exec();
  }));
}
```

Note: with `Promise.all` there is no limit on the number of promises concurrently running. If that is a concern you can either roll your own or use one of the many promise libs that have methods for this.